# cgicc make fails when trying to install cgicc libraries for c++ web programming

Tags: html, c++, cgi

I'm a newbie to c++ web programming. I followed the link tutorialspoint for C++ web programming.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm
I installed the cgicc library, confirgures it but will making i get the following error: I need to usecgicc libraries to make my html work.

Making all in cgicc
    make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/cgicc-3.0.2/cgicc'
    /bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I..    -g -O2 -c CgiEnvironment.cc
    mkdir .libs
    c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c  -fPIC -DPIC CgiEnvironment.cc -o .libs/CgiEnvironment.lo
    c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c CgiEnvironment.cc -o CgiEnvironment.o >/dev/null 2>&1
    mv -f .libs/CgiEnvironment.lo CgiEnvironment.lo
    /bin/sh ../libtool --mode=compile c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I..    -g -O2 -c CgiUtils.cc
    rm -f .libs/CgiUtils.lo
    c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c  -fPIC -DPIC CgiUtils.cc -o .libs/CgiUtils.lo
    CgiUtils.cc:111:30: error: 'string' does not name a type
     CGICCNS unescapeString(const string& src)
                                  ^
    CgiUtils.cc:111:41: error: 'std::__cxx11::string cgicc::unescapeString(const int&)' should have been declared inside 'cgicc'
     CGICCNS unescapeString(const string& src)
                                             ^
    CgiUtils.cc: In function 'std::__cxx11::string cgicc::unescapeString(const int&)':
    CgiUtils.cc:117:18: error: request for member 'begin' in 'src', which is of non-class type 'const int'
       for(iter = src.begin(); iter != src.end(); ++iter) {
                      ^
    CgiUtils.cc:117:39: error: request for member 'end' in 'src', which is of non-class type 'const int'
       for(iter = src.begin(); iter != src.end(); ++iter) {
                                           ^
    Makefile:229: recipe for target 'CgiUtils.lo' failed
    make[1]: *** [CgiUtils.lo] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/to/cgicc-3.0.2/cgicc'
    Makefile:161: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
    make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Please tell me where I'm going wrong! Is there anything else i need to do